# Is there a method for evaluating authenticity of revelation to other nations?

Tags: gentiles, prophecies

Are we provided with a method, measure or test for the validity or authenticity of prophecy or revelation given to other nations, speaking more specifically about revelations given to non-Jewish prophets in a message independent of Judaism.

Comment: What methods do we have for testing revelation to our nation?

Answer (score 2):

[There is a Midrash](/q/57484) that says that since the time of Balaam (and in response to a prayer of Moses) there would never again be a gentile prophet. In which case the test is: if the gentile says he's a prophet, he's lying.

Comment: Vayikra Rabba 1:10-12? Referencing Song of Songs?

Comment: This idea is based on Bavli Brachot 7a, where it says that, in response to Moshe's prayer, the Shechinah will not rest on non-Jews,

Comment: @mevaqesh Please don't edit to change others' transliteration schemes. The standard on MY is that there is no standard, so long as it is (somewhat) intelligible, and were everyone to edit according to their whim, then Eiyn laDhDhabhar Soap.